# What are reasons for white areas on monitors?

Tags: display

I've got a monitor, that has such problem (whiter, washed-out colours on the bottom area):

[image]

it's more visible on black screen and on coloured screen, it's less noticeable:

[image]
Bezel doesn't seem to pressure, Also, in that area, i can see "white-noise"-like "waves".

Can this be cured? (is that dust, or it's hardware failure, that can't be fixed? ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be backlight bleed. As for a fix there is not many options. First see if anything is applying preassure to the screen, such as the bezel. Chances are it is not but it never hurts to check. A better option, if possible is to return it or use the warranty to get it replaced or fixed.

Comment: unfortuntely i can't return. need the "fix" but that's what i've asked. seems no simple-fix. 

bezel doesnt seem to pressure, might be the "bleed" you have said. also, in that area, it's more noticeable the "air/gas-like waves" (or "white-noise")

Comment: I have done research before buying monitors and from what I read some monitors (higher or lower end) both can have these backlight bleeding defects even right out of the box.